# Regex for these strings

Tags: regex

I'm having difficulty catching some strings. I want a regex to catch the strings in this list:

1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
4. 4
5. 5
6. 6
7. 7
8. 8a
9. 8b
10. 8c
11. 8d
12. 9

There will only be a letter after the number 8, and 8 will always have a following letter (a-d). The rest of the numbers will not have a letter following them.

Thanks

Comment: can 8 be without letter following ?

Comment: No, 8 will always have a following letter (a-d)

Comment: So "123" will have three matches? And "8f" will not match? And "123a" will have still three matches (excluding the "a")? This needs more detailed specifications... And also add your attempt and why it has a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
[1-7]|9|8[abcd]
```

Depending on whether you want the *whole* string to match, so that nothing else follows or precedes the match, you may need to add anchors:

```
^([1-7]|9|8[abcd])$
```

Or, alternatively, if you just want to match digits that are *not* followed by a letter (a, b, c, d) except when it is 8 (where it is required), then:

```
([1-7]|9)(?![abcd])|8[abcd]
```